# Angular - how to set automatic save for file changes?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am working in VSCode and using `ng serve -o`. I want to have automatic saving after I update each file and then display the updates in the browser during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File > Auto Save`, this will automatically save it after a delay.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics (go to the section `Save/Auto Save`)

For the updates to display on the browser, this should happen automatically if you are doing `ng serve`.